# Is there a name for this kind of integral?

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, fractional-calculus

Just wondering if anyone knows the name of this kind of integral

\begin{equation}
X_t = \int_0^t \frac{f(s)}{(t-s)^\alpha} ds
\end{equation}

It's kinda unique as when $s \to t$ then $\frac{f(s)}{(t-s)^\alpha} \to \infty$ if $f(s)$ is finite.

I know it's been used in fractional calculus, but then is there a specific name for this kind of integral? Looking for the name in order to search for some numerical method...

Looking for numerical method for this kind of integral... Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps "singular integral" ... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_integral

Comment: @GEdgar just what I needed! Thanks a lot!!